# Jquery How maintain state between postbacks in jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using jquery tab and following js method, how and what can i modify it to maintain state of tab between postbacks? (This resets tabs to first tab after page_load)

$(document).ready(function() {          //When page loads...
   $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab         $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content          //On Click Event         $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
$("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
  $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab             $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
 var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
 $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content             return false;         });

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this problem when I first started using jQuery. My solution was to use an `<asp:HiddenField />` to store the active tab index on tabselect.

ASP.Net allows client-side code to modify an `<asp:HiddenField />` so it will retain its value across postbacks.

On `document.ready`, simply restore the active tab by setting the `selected` tab during intialization:

Example:

```
$('div#divMyTabs').tabs({
    selected: function () {
        var tabFromPostback = $('input#<%=hfActiveTab.ClientID %>').val();
        return tabFromPostback === '' ? 0 : tabFromPostback;   //Default to first.
    },
    select:   function (e, ui) {
        $('input#<%=hfActiveTab.ClientID %>').val(ui.index);
    }
});
```